# How to change app settings where only admin was converted by Facebook to a business account

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

We created and deployed two Facebook apps a few years ago. Several months ago, Facebook reclassified the account associated with these apps as "Business" rather than "Personal". Once that happened, we lost access to our apps. Any attempt to access the app's developer URL immediate redirects us back to our basic Facebook wall.

Now, we are receiving emailed warnings from Facebook that our apps need privacy policy updates, and if we don't make them, then "actions will be taken". Since we can't access the apps, we obviously can't modify the privacy policy.

How can we rectify this issue? We need to change the app settings and/or add new admins to the app.

Comment: I think that this is not within the Stackoverflow rules for posts, but with a tag with more followers, you might get an answer or a better place to post, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit app settings via the API:

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ for more details

Most of the app's settings can be changed directly via the API using the User access token for one of the admins.

You can add additional admins via the API - get an access token for the business account which is currently the admin of the app, then use the access token to add additional admins

Check that the user you want to add is a valid user to be an app admin (i.e has a mobile number or credit card on file - you can check this by having the user create an app themselves) first, then:

POST to `https://graph.facebook.com/[APP ID HERE]/roles?access_toke=<ACCESS TOKEN>` with parameters:

- `user` - The User ID of the user to add
- `role` - The role to add them to, valid options being 'administrators', 'developers', 'testers' or 'insights users'

Comment: I'm trying to add users to a few orphaned applications and the APP_ID/roles endpoint returns the following response:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Comment: Are you definitely using the access token for the business account? - I see my original answer said the app access token worked, i don't believe that's the case, editing now

Comment: @Igy Thanks for your answer here before it was closed. We're experiencing this same problem and trying to figure out how to take control. I believe I am authenticating properly to the 'roles' URL you mentioned, and the response I get is {"data":[]}. And if I test this same type of query using an app that I still have control of, the "data" array comes back with the actual roles. So it seems like this app truly has no accounts assigned to it, which means I can't reassign.

Comment: @Igy To be clear, the response I get when I do a GET using the app access token is an empty array for data[]. When I do a POST using the previous owner's access token (found here when logged into facebook with the business account: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/), I receive a "true" response. I also subsequently received a notification email from Facebook indicating a new administrator was added to our roles for the app, but alas, that admin account still does not see this app listed in the apps area of developers.facebook.com. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Igy I've filed a bug with Facebook here, FWIW: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/525030474204758